# How can I add a constant-valued column to a SQLAlchemy query response?

Tags: sqlalchemy

To get the equivalent of

```
select a, b from very_wide_table
```

in SQLAlchemy I can write

```
VeryWideTable.query().with_entities(VeryWideTable.a, VeryWideTable.b)
```

What would be the equivalent of

```
select a, b, 'hello' from very_wide_table
```

I tried `add_columns` but it wants a column object and I don't know how to specify a fixed string. I tried to add a fixed string to `with_entities` but that was interpreted as a column name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`literal`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal):

```
.with_entities(VeryWideTable.a, VeryWideTable.b, literal("hello"))
```